# How to share encrypted data in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

How can some data encrypted on Computer A be decrypted and red by Computer B without a shared secret or  a PKI infrastructure?

The thing i wanna acomplish is a password manager for our local intranet. Yea there are many out there but i wanna try it on my own. So its a simple web app where users can log in and store their passwords in it. The data is encrpyted with theier credentials. One main feature is that users can share passwords with other users from the plattform. The Problem ist how can user B read shared data from user A without knowing his password for decryption?

Any good ideas?

Thx

Comment: that's exactly what PKI is for. person A gets person B's public key and encrypts the data. the encrypted data is sent to person B, and person B uses their PRIVATE key to decrypt it.

Comment: Right but so the users have to exchange the public keys and that was not the way i want to do it

Comment: You don't have to have the users explicitly exchange public keys. That could be a part of the handshake or share/transfer process

Comment: Ok i understand. What about security of storing the keys ? Its a web app so the keys will remain on the server. Isnt this kind of insecure ?

Comment: which begs the question of why you want to encrypt this stuff. Why encrypt it at all? Person A uploads a file and says "this is for person B". As long as your code provides the necessary "are you person B" security filtering, no one but B could ever access that file, unless they hacked into the server somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cryptography engineering is a narrow and specialized discipline, and wanting to build a password manager is a non-trivial undertaking with a scope that far exceeds the Q&A nature of a StackOverflow answer.